# Message Attachment not showing in web chat, but text messages are showing.

Tags: botframework

Message Attachment not showing in web chat after I embed it on a web page, but text messages are showing properly. The JSON returned is correct, and works fine when I test from the Bot Publisher page or from a Bot Emulator.

Doesn't the web chat support attachments?

Comment: Can you test this again with the latest release?  I'm unable to reproduce this error.   Thanks!

Comment: What version of WebChat are you using? Can you share your code that reproduces the error? Are you using .NET or Node SDK for botbuilder? What version of the SDK are you using?